# Execute Ant targets within environment set up by .cmd file

Tags: batch-file, ant

I want to kick off an .exe from an Ant script. The .exe has a requirement that a .cmd file be run first to prep the environment. To be clear: if I open a console, run the .cmd first, and then my .exe, all is well. I'm working in Windows 7.

This is what I currently have but it isn't working, I assume because the .cmd runs as its own process, and when control returns to Ant I've lost that scope so the next target runs and doesn't know anything about what happened in the .cmd file. Or at least that's what appears to be happening.

I've messed around with different cmd switches, spawn true/false,  etc. but nothing really seems to be working and I am not sure what to Google for to see a working example of this situation.

```
<target name="-someTarget">
  <exec executable="cmd" spawn="false">
    <arg value="/c" />
    <arg value="somefile.cmd" />
  </exec>
  <exec executable="some.exe" spawn="false">
    <arg value="-whatever" />
      <arg value="somevalue" /> <!-- etc. -->
  </exec>
</target>
```

This is my workaround for now, but I would rather keep everything in my Ant script if possible.

```
<target name="-someTarget">
  <exec executable="cmd" spawn="false">
    <arg line='/c somefile.bat "c:\some path\" an-arg "c:\another path\.txt" "c:\and another\.log"' />
  </exec>
</target>
```

somefile.bat:

```
call %1\somefile.cmd
call %1\some.exe %2 %3 %4
```

Comment: But you are not "keeping everything in your Ant script" when you have an external `.cmd` that you need to execute to set environment variables. And since you are relying on `.cmd` outside of Ant, is it so bad to have yet another file (`.bat`) there?

I'd honestly look into porting the functionality of the `.cmd` into Ant in the first place, to stick with your own preference to keep everything in Ant

Comment: I'm new to Ant, so this is a learning experience. I was trying to keep as much in the script as possible without fragmenting this process. I got it working with an external batch file, and no it doesn't seem so bad. The .cmd file is a proprietary script that is HUGE and I don't want to mess with it, so your suggestion of porting the .cmd to Ant isn't an option. I'll give your answer a shot though, thank you for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'arg line=' method suggested by Slav works as long as the DOS call command is used:

```
<exec executable="cmd">
  <arg line="/c call some.cmd &amp; call some.exe" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call both on the same command line

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg line="/c somefile.cmd &amp;"/>
    <arg value="some.exe"/>
    <arg value="-whatever"/>
    <arg value="somevalue"/>
    <!-- etc. -->
</exec>
```

The reason for the `<arg line>` is that you can't supply just `&amp;` to `<arg value>` (at least that didn't work for me.

Comment: Same problem with this method, the cmd ran but didn't stick. The exe in the next step doesn't know about it: "The user environment was not adequately prepared to continue execution." etc.

Comment: I think I already tried this method to be honest. I've done so many different combinations of things it's getting hard to tell :)

Comment: I finally got it. I needed a "call" before some.exe.